# Can anyone interpret what these instructions mean? Trying to install a JVM to a mac

Tags: java, r, bash, macos

Please bear with me. I'm a biology student trying to perform Species Distribution Modeling of certain plant species in Australia using R Studio (specifically using a Maximum Entropy model) and I have a limited understanding of the command line.

In order to do this, I need to use the rJava package in R Studio. While the installation seems to work, when I run the command:

```
library(rJava)
```

I get this warning message:

```
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
```

So I found this tutorial online:

https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/86#issuecomment-261039681.

Towards the bottom of the page, the user **gwarnes-mdsol** gives a step-by-step guide to fixing this problem using my mac's command-line. I am supposed to install Java, uninstall any existing rJava packages, and then run a few lines of code that he wrote out. However, I can't seem to get past this step. What does he mean when he says to add the export command to the the filepath he supplied? Am I supposed to fill in portions of this code with filepaths that are specific to my computer?

```
# Add the following lines to /Users/<userid>/.bashrc:
# Set JAVA_HOME so rJava package can find it
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)/jre
```

I'm not sure where to begin with this. I've tried downloading a JDK (jdk-11.0.6_osx-x64_bin.tar.gz) and renaming it JAVA_HOME but then I don't know where to put it in my computer. I don't know where to find a .bashrc file. How can I run this code properly?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: He means add the line beginning with `export` to the file /Users/userid/.bashrc, where userid is your user name on the system.

Comment: so like this? /Users/userid/.bashrc export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)/jre

Comment: Open up `~/.bashrc` with a text editor (`vim`, `emacs`, whatever you're used to), and modify its contents to add the `JAVA_HOME=...` line.

Comment: You need to open the .bashrc file in a text editor. If your user name is _e.g._ joseph, it should be in /Users/joseph/.bashrc. Try "ls -a /Users/joseph" in Terminal to find the file. Create the file if it doesn't exist. Add that line to it. Save it.

Comment: I have .bash_profile, .bash_sessions, and .bash_history but I do not have .bashrc. I will create that now and try your method. Thank you!

Comment: Do I need to modify the export JAVA_HOME=... part to make it specific to my computer?